# Coordinate system conversion format

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I'm a beginner in the use of QGIS and I have a problem with a coordinate conversion for creating a map in QGIS. I have some coordinates that have been collected with GPS in the field in this way: [image: coordinates] that should be a degree minutes format (18° 59.072' S, 48° 27.776' E).

I would like to convert them in degree, minutes and seconds or UTM format in an automatic way, to have all the data standardized and create a map in QGIS.

Is there any tool or plugin I can use to do this?

Comment: Once you used e.g. Excel to bring your data into a format QGIS can interpret as DM, you can use `to_decimal()` in the field calculator.

Comment: Or using QGIS expressions to directly format your input values and convert them to DMS. For the correct expression to do so, you should post a sample of your coordinates **as text**, not as screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

You have a [DM format](https://flyandwire.com/2020/08/10/back-to-basics-latitude-and-longitude-dms-dd-ddm/) and want to convert it to [DMS](https://flyandwire.com/2020/08/10/back-to-basics-latitude-and-longitude-dms-dd-ddm/). Your screenshot shows that the input coordinates consist of digits with two points, separating as well degrees from minutes and acting as decimal separator for minutes, in some cases also containing a letter like E: `18.59.072` and `E048.27.776`.

1. Use [`regexp_replace()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-replace) to convert the textstring input to a format that can be interpreted correctly as coordinate input for `to_decimal()` function argument. This format looks like `'6°21\'16.445'`, so you have to replace the first point with `°` followed by a space: `18° 59.072'` and `E048° 27.776'`
2. Convert this to decimal format with [`to_decimal()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#to-decimal): `18.984533333333335` and `48.46293333333333`
3. Convert to dms with [`to_dms()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#to-dms) to get: `18°59′4.3″` and `48°27′46.6″`. See the linked help for how you can change the output format.

So all together, it looks like this. In line 4, replace the coordinates textstring with the name of the field that contains the x-coordinates value. For the y-coordinate, replace `x` with `y` on line 9:

```
to_dms(
    to_decimal(
        regexp_replace(
            '18.59.072',  -- your input coordinates or fieldname
            '(.)(\\.)(.*)',
            '\\1° \\3'''
        )
    ),
    'x', -- replace with y for y coordinates
    1
)
```